# how to get not indexed pages using google search console api

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

I am looking for a way to get 404 pages of mywebsite using google api search console
I have tried this way but it returned 0 rows despite there are 404 pages in my website

```
   $service = new Google_Service_Webmasters($gClient);
        $queryRequest = new SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
        $queryRequest->setStartDate('1950-01-01'); // Set the earliest date for which you have 
        $queryRequest->setEndDate(date('Y-m-d')); // Set the current date
 $queryRequest->setDimensions(['page']);
 /*$queryRequest->setDimensionFilterGroups([
     [
         'filters' => [
             [
                 'dimension' => 'page',
                 'operator' => 'contains',
                 'expression' => '404',
             ],
         ],
     ],
```